# error with elif and if statements

Tags: python

I am trying to write a heater function but I am having a few difficulties. I am fairly new to Python.

I want my heater to run for 15000 seconds but for the first 120 seconds (inclusive of 120) I want it to follow a linear path `T = 0.0804 * t + 16.081` and then after 120 seconds I want it to remain constant for the rest of the remaining time at the final temperature found from the linear equation.

The code I have written is below which I am getting errors with

```
import math, numpy as np
from random import *

a = 0.0804
time = range(15001)

for time in xrange(15001):
   if 0 < = time < = 120:
     Temp = a * np.array(time) + 18.3
   elif time > 121:
     Temp = Temp[120]
```

Errors:

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/py3c‌​ompat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
      202 else:
      203 filename = fname
  --> 204 builtin.execfile(filename, *where)
/Users/mariepears/Desktop/heaterfunction.py in <module>
    () 16 print T
       17 elif t>121:
  ---> 18 T=T[120]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`
```

Comment: well, what errors? (and I don't even know what to say about your variable names)

Comment: Please edit it into the question so it's actually readable.

Comment: @MariePears It would definitely improve readability if you would edit that into your question.

Comment: `T[120]` is incorrect since `T` is a number, not a sequence.

Comment: Please 1. Paste the error message into the post 2. Highlight it 3. Press CTRL+K, or click the two brackets at the top of the edit textbox, so we can make sense of the error message.

Comment: So is T a t or A T or a T in a t? Answers on a postcard to WhyYouShouldNameYourVariablesProperly Inc at PO Box 52

Comment: In the OP's defense, they are trying to port old scientific code to python, and the variable names in old scientific code are *never* clear.  They usually are the single letter varaibles used in the corresponding math equations, hence `T` and `t`.  Since this was actually a well-formed question with an actual code example by someone honestly trying to learn, let's give them a break and try to make SO a little more friendly.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are getting muddled up between `time` (the `range()` result, so a list of integers) and `Temp` (uppercase, the loop variable, an integer).

```
time = range(15001)
for Temp in xrange(15001):
   if 0 <= Temp <= 120:
     Temp = a * np.array(time) + 18.3
   elif Temp > 121:
     Temp = time[120]
```

Because `time` is a *list*, you should not try to test against if it is smaller or greater than a single integer either; `0 <= time <= 120` makes no sense; ordering between different types always places numbers first, then orders them by *type name*; integers are *always* lower than lists, so `time > 121` is **always** `True`.

```
temperatures = []
for second in xrange(121):
    last = a * second + 18.3
    temperatures.append(last)

temperatures += temperatures[120:] * (15000 - 120)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
temperatures = [a * min(sec, 120) + 18.3 for sec in xrange(150001)]
```

Comment: I have re-edit my names. I want the time to loop and produce the different temperatures and then I want to hold the temperature constant after 120 seconds.

Comment: @MariePears: then why not loop directly over `time`?

Comment: @MariePears: what is the calculation per second supposed to *do*? The `np.array()` call makes no sense, really.

Comment: Yes I want to loop over time I think maybe I should have for time in xrange? Sorry am a novice.

Comment: I wanted to be able to multiply a list of values eg from 0 to 120 seconds by a value and thought I needed a numpy array to enable the multiplication?

Comment: @MariePears: it is not clear what you expect the multiplication to be here.

Comment: I have the equation Temp = 0.0804*time +18.3 and it is only true for the first 120 seconds of time. After that the temperature is constant. So I want to be able to loop through time between 0to120 to generate temperatures. How do I write this if not with a numpy array?

Comment: See my latest version.

Comment: If i wanted to get return the temperature each time it loops it is possible to write this without changing it completely?

Comment: I am not certain what you mean; the code *collects* all the temperatures in a list. You can return only *once* from a function; are you looking for a generator instead?

Comment: Yes I think I am looking for a generator instead. I have since realised that I need the temperature to be called each time not as a continuous list. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @MariePears: use my `for` loop, replace `temperatures.append(last)` with `yield last` and you have a generator.

Comment: import math, numpy as np
from random import *

a = 0.0804

temperatures = []
for second in xrange(121):
    last = a * second + 18.3
yield last

temperatures += temperatures[120:] * (15000 - 120)

It says 'yield' outside function

Comment: @MariePears: if you wanted this to be a generator function, then you do need to put it in a *function*. See [The Python yield keyword explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767) for more info on the `yield` keyword.

Comment: a = 0.0804

def temperatures():
 for second in xrange(121):
      last = a * second + 18.3
  yield last

mygenerator = temperatures() #create a generator
print(mygenerator)
for last in mygenerator:
 temperatures += temperatures[120:] * (15000 - 120)
 print(temperatures). It says that the error is 'function' object is not subscriptable. I am not sure which bit I am meant to be editing. Sorry am really struggling, even if this is easy

Comment: Perhaps make this is a new question then? A generator function needs to be called first to produce the generator, but even then it is not going to be subscriptable; generators just produce one item after another, but once produced you cannot ask it for item 0 or item 1 or any other item in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, `T` is an integer from `xrange(150001)`. In the `then` clause of your `if` statement, you set `T` to be an array, but that doesn't have anything to do with what happens in the `elif` clause.

In general, you should not reset the loop variable in the loop (and that's probably not what you mean to do).

In your edited version, you have `Temp = Temp[120]` which is no better: `Temp` is still not an array here, so you can't subscript it.

Comment: I put Temp=Temp[120] as I wanted the 120th position value to remain constant. I realise that it is probably wrong but I couldn't work out how to write what I wanted